# How to track only a block of a file with git?

Tags: git, command-line

I want to commit only a part of a file with git, is there a way to do that?

Comment: The short answer is "no": a commit is a snapshot of files (and that's *whole* files). But if what you mean is that you made multiple independent changes to one file, and you would like to make a commit that has, as its snapshot, the entire file with only *one* of those changes *applied*, then yes, there is a way to do that. It's not clear if that's what you're asking, though.

Answer (score 2):

Git tracks the contents of directories by maintaining snapshots of them. (see "[git from the bottom up](https://jwiegley.github.io/git-from-the-bottom-up/1-Repository/1-directory-content-tracking.html)"). So you can not track only part of a file *directly*.

But what you *can* do is *build* a file by concatenating several tracked and untracked files. This could be accomplished by a build tool like `make` or `scons`, or by a simple shell script or batch file. The untracked source files and the resulting file should be listed in the `gitignore` file so that git doesn't track them.

Answer (score 0):

May I ask why you only want to commit part of the file?

I can't think of an instance where I wouldn't want to commit the entire file. 
(The changes you want to commit may be reliant on changes you made to your local file that you are not committing and are misleading to others working on your branch.)

If you don't want to overwrite code that you think is correct, then I would recommend opening a branch so that you don't overwrite that code until you are sure that your changes are necessary.

```
$ git checkout -b <branch-name>
```

If you are using GitHub you can open a Pull Request for your changes with

```
$ git push origin <branch-name>
```

Then comment on the specific line you have a question about and @mention the original author so they can clarify intent.